# Mysql how merge table data by column

Tags: mysql, sql

`GROUP BY` does not work for this

I have this:

```
-----------------
name  col1  col2
-----------------
a     null  1
b     null  3
a     3     null
b     4     null
```

I need this result:

```
-----------------
name  col1  col2
-----------------
a     3     1
b     4     3
```

Comment: `select name, max(col1), max(col2) from table group by name`

Comment: and if you have another row (a, 5, 5)? How change your result?

Comment: And the row (c, 1, 2)?

Comment: no, i dont have (a, 5, 5) because this table is result of  UNION of two tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX` to eliminate the NULLs and then the `GROUP BY` function.

```
SELECT name, MAX(col1) AS col1, MAX(col2) AS col2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
```

Output:

```
name col1 col2
a    3    1
b    4    3
```

Since you said `GROUP BY` does not work for this I am assuming it is part of a bigger query, maybe use sub queries to get your results?

```
SELECT t.name, 
      (SELECT MAX(ta.col1) FROM yourtable ta WHERE ta.name = t.name) AS col1,
      (SELECT MAX(tb.col2) FROM yourtable tb WHERE tb.name = t.name) AS col2
FROM yourtable t
GROUP BY t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `GROUP BY` is perfect here:

```
select name, max(col1) col1, max(col2) col2
from tablename
group by name
```